# How to secure method in controller from invalid id (not exist in DB) in URL?

Tags: java, url, spring-security, controller

```
@Auditable(action = AuditingAction.VIEW_CATEGORY)
@GetMapping("/api/category/{id}")
@PreAuthorize(value = "(@categoryServiceImpl.getCategoryById(#id)) != null ")
public ResponseEntity<CategoryLinkDTO> getCategoryById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Category category = categoryService.getCategoryById(id);
    Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(CategoryController.class).getCategoryById(category.getId())).withRel("category");
    CategoryLinkDTO publicDTO = DTOBuilder.buildDtoForEntity(category, CategoryLinkDTO.class, selfLink);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(publicDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It works, but here are 2 request in DB

```
@PreAuthorize(value = "(@categoryServiceImpl.getCategoryById(#id)) != null ")
Category category = categoryService.getCategoryById(id);
```

Comment: I think @PreAutorize is not the right thing for the purpose. Why wouldn't you simply check for null and return the corresponding response entity yourself?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `@PostAuthorize("#returnObject.body != null")`?